# Extracting time from the json file and wanted to produce output for time difference between startdate and end date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to extract a part of json file to get the starttime and end time of jobs running in the application which is in utc timezone format, how could i extract the date in readable format.

```
$time2 = $("{0:N1}" -f $data.value.CompletedJobs.EndTime)
$time2 = $("{0:N1}" -f $data.value.CompletedJobs.EndTime)
```

Output- is as follows

```
Start_Time  End_Time
2018-07-10T05:20:00.6999915Z    2018-07-10T05:33:00.9956512Z
```

I would like to convert it to more readable format and also want to perform the check for difference of time duration, how could i proceed on that, can anyone please suggest

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
[datetime]"2018-07-10T05:33:00.9956512Z"
```

or in your case

```
$time2 = [datetime]("{0:N1}" -f $data.value.CompletedJobs.EndTime)
```

would convert the value into a .NET DateTime object which you can use further.

Comment: Thank you @TobyU for your inputs here, i am getting the output but at the output i am getting as follows: DUR
00:13:00.2956597  so how can we restrict only to minutes, is there any function for that

Comment: Can you show me some more of your code? @G.vinayKumar

Comment: Hello TobyU, I somehow managed to work on and got the desired output, many thanks for you

Comment: Glad to hear that @G.vinayKumar. If my answer is a part of the solution, it would be nice of you to mark it as such.